Why does Jech assume $V = L$ in his proof of the independence of $\mathsf{AC}$?
As title states, I'm curious as to why Jech explicitly works under a model of $\mathsf{ZFC} + V = L$ when proving the relative consistency of $\neg\mathsf{AC}$ in the "Indepence of the Axiom of Choice" chapter of his Set Theory book. As far as I can see, he doesn't seem to make use of properties specific to $V = L$ throughout his proof of the fact, so is it actually necessary or just some standard procedure to make sure one is working on a nice metatheoretical setting?

In part, $V=L$ were the only relevant models at the time to begin with. The way we proved that $V\neq L$ is even consistent was when Cohen added a new real to a model without adding new ordinals. And we certainly didn't have any other models of $\sf ZFC$ other than those.

Which version of the book?

@AsafKaragila Set Theory: The Third Millennium Edition. "Independence of the Axiom of Choice" (221-223).

Jech's assumption of $V=L$ is unnecessary and is unused, as you point out. This may have been a remnant from a previous draft where using $L(A)$, rather than $\mathrm{HOD}(A)$,1 had been used. It could be that there was, at one point or another (and possibly in a later chapter), a proof that in that model every set can be linearly ordered, which is ever-so-slightly simpler to prove under $V=L$. It could also be the case that Jech simply didn't notice.
Or, it could be that Jech wanted that $M\subseteq N\subseteq M[G]$ will hold, and without working with the full apparatus of symmetric systems it is hard to justify why $M\subseteq\mathrm{HOD}(A)$, and it does not have to be true, as $\mathrm{HOD}$ can be very different between models. But if one assumes $V=L$ holds in $M$, then $L=L^M=L^N=L^{M[G]}$, and so the inclusion is easy.
My money is probably on the last one.


Nowadays this would usually be written as $\mathrm{HOD}_{A\cup\{A\}}$ to avoid the confusing notation of $\mathrm{HOD}(A)$ being either "ordinal definable over $A$" or "the smallest model containing both $\mathrm{HOD}$ and $A$".

